# In 十日と待たずに what does the と mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-と

Probably a silly question, but in this sentence:

> 仕事ができなかったら**十日と待たずに**解雇されるだろうと思う。

What does the と in 十日と待たずに mean? Is it the "if" と, e.g. "when/if 10 days pass, I'd get fired without hesitation?". Shouldn't it say 十日だと (with the だ added)?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sentence says "(I) will be fired *in no more than 10 days*." `(time)と待たずに` is a common set phrase which literally means "without waiting for (time)".

This と is not "if" nor "then". The role of と here corresponds to the sixth entry of [デジタル大辞泉's definition](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154670/m0u/%E3%81%A8/).

> ６ （数量を表す語に付き、打消しの表現を伴って）その範囲以上には出ない意を表す。…までも。「全部で一〇〇円―かからない」「一〇〇キロ―走らなかった」

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much. Where did you find the fact that "(time)と待たずに" is a common set phrase? Google doesn't seem to be helping and none of the online dictionaries I've tried come up with any useful info.

Comment: Ah, I thought it's common without looking at anything, but [BCCWJ Corpus](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/) returned only 2 results which were exactly the same. A similar phrase とかからず returned 8 results. Another common way is to use も instead of と (10日も待たずに).